# C++ lambda expression for sort follows relative ordering

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

I solved a leetcode problem [2191. Sort the Jumbled Numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-the-jumbled-numbers/). My doubt is why my code is able to maintain the relative ordering in sorting when mapped values of the elements are equal. Here is the Leetcode question description:

You are given a **0-indexed** integer array mapping which represents the mapping rule of a shuffled decimal system. mapping[i] = j means digit i should be mapped to digit j in this system.

The **mapped value** of an integer is the new integer obtained by replacing each occurrence of digit i in the integer with mapping[i] for all 0 <= i <= 9.

You are also given another integer array nums. Return the array nums sorted in **non-decreasing** order based on the **mapped values** of its elements.

**Notes:**

- Elements with the same mapped values should appear in the **same relative order** as in the input.
- The elements of nums should only be sorted based on their mapped values and **not be replaced** by them.

**Example 1**

```
Input: mapping = [8,9,4,0,2,1,3,5,7,6], nums = [991,338,38]
Output: [338,38,991]
Explanation: 
Map the number 991 as follows:
1. mapping[9] = 6, so all occurrences of the digit 9 will become 6.
2. mapping[1] = 9, so all occurrences of the digit 1 will become 9.
Therefore, the mapped value of 991 is 669.
338 maps to 007, or 7 after removing the leading zeros.
38 maps to 07, which is also 7 after removing leading zeros.
Since 338 and 38 share the same mapped value, they should remain in the same relative order, so 338 comes before 38.
Thus, the sorted array is [338,38,991].
```

**Example 2**

```
Input: mapping = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], nums = [789,456,123]
Output: [123,456,789]
Explanation: 789 maps to 789, 456 maps to 456, and 123 maps to 123. Thus, the sorted array is [123,456,789].
```

**My Accepted C++ Code**

```
class Solution {
public:
    // function for converting a given number n according to mapped values
    int calculate(int n, vector<int>& map){
        int ans = 0, mul = 1;
        if(n == 0)
            return map[0];
        while(n != 0){
            int digit = n % 10;
            ans += map[digit] * mul;
            mul *= 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    
    vector<int> sortJumbled(vector<int>& mapping, vector<int>& nums) {
        // C++ lambda expression added inside sort function
        sort(begin(nums), end(nums), [&](int x , int y){
            return calculate(x, mapping) < calculate(y, mapping);
        });
        return nums;
    }
};
```

**My Doubt**

Let me take the Example 1, where nums = [991,338,38] and it's corresponding mapped values = [669, 7, 7]. Here the expected output is [338,38,991] and my code is working correctly. My doubt is that why 338 is coming first in the output as my lambda expression only checking a < b condition. So whenever a < b is true, then a comes first in the sorted order otherwise b comes. According to my code what I think is that when calculate(338, mapping) < calculate(38, mapping) is called, it returns false right? So 38 should come first right? Can someone please explain how my code is doing the stable sort when elements have equal mapped values.

Comment: It appears your compiler's `std::sort()` algorithm is stable, at least for the number of elements you're sorting. It's not guaranteed by the language specification (there's a `std::stable_sort` if you explicitly want that behaviour).

Comment: Thanks for replying. when I replace my lambda expression as " return calculate(x, mapping) <= calculate(y, mapping); ", Now this is not outputting the correct result in relative ordering. for input in example 1, it outputs [38,338,991]. why? why no relative ordering followed here?

Comment: Because a `<=` comparison does not induce a *strict weak ordering* and so the comparison violates a precondition of `std::sort`. You get undefined behavior.

Comment: Your understanding of ordering is incorrect. "a is not ordered before b" does *not* imply "b is ordered before a"; they may be unordered (i.e. equivalent). When you change to `<=`, your ordering says "all equal elements are ordered before each other", which is impossible.

Comment: "Stable" means that it always maintains the relative ordering. "Not stable" doesn't mean that it never does, only that it isn't guaranteed. You can't conclude stability from a finite number of examples.

Comment: I tried to print the comparator argument x and y, I found that when comparator is called index of x is always greater than index of y. So if calculate(x) < calculate(y), then x is placed before y in the sorted order. if calculate(x) > calculate(y), comparator return false. so y is placed before x in sorted order. in case calculate(x) == calculate(y), then also comparator returns false, then y is placed before x, remember that index of y is less than index of x. I think this is the reason why relative ordering is maintained in my code. Please correct me if I am wrong.